# Forming a compound with the second word starting with a vowel

Tags: grammar-choice, affixes, vowel, interfixes

For both Latin and Greek, what rules govern the formation of a compound of two words, with the second word starting with a vowel?

I'm specifically most interested in the rules for Latin, since this question was born out of my attempts to form a specific epithet for a made-up species, via a compound of *rapax* and *atrox* in that order (the other way around is obvious: *atrocirapax*); the first thing that I came up with was *rapaciatrox* using the Latin interfix *-i-*, but then I remembered that in the case of *magnanimus* (the etymological root of English "magnanimous"), the interfix was dropped completely. Yet *rapacatrox* doesn't seem right to me.

That being said, I am also interested in how it works for Greek, since some Greek words that technically start with a vowel are actually pronounced with an "h" sound preceding the vowel (e.g. ἁρπάζω *harpázō*).

Comment: This isn't directly related, but I remember reading somewhere that compound words were more common and productive in Greek than in Latin, and compound words in Latin(at least, the recent, transparent ones) were mainly concentrated in the higher registers of the language, and possibly used in part due to influence from Greek. There is some mention of it in post #5 here: [Compound words in classical Latin - Latin Discussion](http://latindiscussion.com/forum/latin/compound-words-in-classical-latin.23883/)

Comment: Also here if you have access to JSTOR: [The Form of Nominal Compounds in Latin](https://www.jstor.org/stable/310363?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents),
George D. Chase, 
*Harvard Studies in Classical Philology*
Vol. 11 (1900), pp. 61-72

Comment: No, I don't have access, but thanks anyway. BTW, I've slightly edited the original post to clarify the context.

Comment: More context is always good. It looks like my comment about the frequency of compounds in Classical Latin is not very relevant for your purposes, since you are forming a "scientific Latin" name.

Comment: A linguistically trained user can certainly comment, but I'm pretty sure that your example *-i-* is not an interfix.

Comment: @brianpck: Not a linguistically trained user, but I think "[interfix](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Interfix)" is a fair description of *-i-* in Latin, insofar as the word "interfix" is useful at all. Chase says the *-i-* was analogical in a number of environments, rather than just being a phonetically regular development of the final vowel of the first stem in word-internal positions, so it seems to be the result of some degree of morphologization.

Comment: I created the tag for you. However, unless there are more questions with the tag or someone writes a [short tag description (use guidance)](http://latin.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/384), the tag will be automatically deleted after some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Latin, the rule is simply that the connecting *-i-* does not appear before a vowel, as in your *magn-animus*, or using a third-declension adjective (like *rapax*):

> *grandaevus* "aged" < *grandi-* "great" + *aevum* "age"

So *rapacatrox* seems to be correct. The exception is that the *-i-* does appear when the first word is monosyllabic, e.g.:

> *triennium* "three-year period" < *tri-* "three" + *annus* "year"

For Greek, the first of the two vowels is lost, e.g.

> αὐτάρκης "self-sufficient" < αὐτο- "self" + ἀρκέω "suffice"

The exception is when the second word began with digamma, e.g.

> αὐτοετής "in the same year" < αὐτο- + (ϝ)έτος "year"
>   φερέοικος "snail" < φερε- "carry" + (ϝ)οῖκος "house"

Though in such cases there is sometimes contraction:

> ἀργός (long ᾱ) "idle" < ἀ- "not" + (ϝ)έργος "deed"
>   Δημῶναξ (personal name) < δῆμο- "people" + (ϝ)άναξ "lord"

When the second word begins with a rough breathing, this aspirates a preceding voiceless stop:

> αὐθάδης "stubborn, self-pleasing" < αὐτο- + ἁδ- "please"

Comment: I see. So... on a side note, would I be correct in assuming that the "c" in _rapacatrox_ is pronounced as a hard C (i.e. "k"), even if the compound is used in modern scientific vocabulary (e.g. binomial nomenclature)?

Comment: @MarqFJA87, yes, it would be pronounced [k] -- in modern pronunciations of Latin some C's are soft, but only those that precede E/I/Y.