# Can Latin do Noun-Noun Adjuncts?

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-identification

First, to begin, I'm a hobbyist with no formal background whatsoever in Latin.  I only know what I can manage to successfully google and read on my own.

Anyway, I've read that Latin can't use nouns as adjectives.  So if you want to say a word like, 'chicken soup,' then you would likely need to place the word chicken into the genitive case or create an adjective and use this word instead.

But while looking up words on Wiktionary I came across this entry, dēfēnsor cīvitātis.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/defensor_civitatis#Latin

I swear, that's just two nouns back to back.  Can anyone explain what I'm seeing and what rule of Latin grammar I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take a look at this related question: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/noun-adjuncts-in-latin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[*Civitatis*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=civitatis&la=la#lexicon) is actually in the genitive, so it fits the rule you mentioned.

The base noun is *civitas*, which is what *civitatis* is linked to on Wiktionary.

Comment: lol well that's egg on my face, I didn't notice when I clicked on civitatis that it took me to civitas.  Thank you!  I thought I was going crazy.

Now I'm debating on leaving this question up or not.  Maybe it'll help someone else out, but it's also now a testament to my lack of attention to detail.

Comment: Hey, you never know whom it might help in the future! I hope you stick around and ask more questions as you progress in Latin!

Comment: The "rule" that the first component must be a case form is not correct.

Comment: @fdb : I don't see any mention here of such a "rule". Was it mentioned in a comment that has been deleted?

Comment: @MPW: see the answer by cmw.

Comment: @fdb that rule doesn't say the first component must be a case form though. It just states that case forms and derived adjectives are generally used instead of noun adjuncts. Chicken going into the genitive is just an example, and the rule as given by Jack gives no explanation as to why chicken and not soup is the one to go in the genitive; the idea that it must be the first component is nowhere mentioned

Comment: @Tristan thank you.  Yes, I'm far from any kind of expert so if anyone reads my question as I asked it, I state what I do understand, and not that it should be considered a comprehensive explanation of the rules. In my example, to explain the rules as I understand them, I suggested chicken would go into the genitive only because the translation into English works well, "soup of chicken."

Comment: @JackPliskin You are correct. Chicken would go into the gentive here or made into an adjective. You wouldn't see the kind of compounding that fdb mentions, which is rare to begin with and not the same phenomenon.

Comment: @fdb *Civitatis* is not a bare stem and follows *defensor*. I don't think what you've mentioned is what the original question was talking about.

Answer (score 8):

You are asking about nominal compounds, whereby the non-final components appear as bare stems, without case endings. These are very common in ancient Indo-European languages like Greek or Sanskrit, but also in many modern IE languages like German. They are less common in Latin, but certainly exist; take for example su-ove-taurilia “sacrifice of pigs, sheep and cattle”, manu-pretium “wages”, not to mention Greek borrowings like hippo-dromus.

Comment: There are also cases where a kind of connective vowel is used like in Greek, such as sacrilegium, parricida, pontifex, but perhaps those are considered to be based on verbal stems?

Comment: @Cerberus More likely analogy to -i stems.

Comment: Oh, really. I wonder, then, how many i-nouns were used in this way to give rise to the analogy.

Comment: @fdb I don't see why we'd need to invoke analogy. This would be the expected reflex of an *e in this position, and not unexpected even for an *o, so having it just be the regular thematic vowel (or, for coinings that obviously postdate vowel reduction, analogy to compounds of thematic stems) seems more parsimonious

Comment: @Tristan. See Buck “Comparative grammar” par. 520, where both possibilities are mentioned.

Comment: @fdb Buck is quite old and outdated these days. Do you know if it's also addressed in more recent works? I don't remember noticing it in Sihler, but I may have just missed it

Comment: @Tristan. For some reason Sihler decided not to update Buck's section on compounds.

Comment: @fdb well, I wasn't asking about compound words initially.  I wasn't trying to understand how to create the word, "chickensoup," but rather, I was trying to better understand the rules for creating the word, "chicken soup." Anyway, I have been super curious about how to create compound words, actually.  Do you have any online resources I could read?

Comment: @Tristan Weiss's discussion is a bit vague but FWIW (p. 264): "In some cases the *i* could theoreticaly continue an old Proto-Italic *i* ... But in most cases *i* is the weakening product of some other vowel ... *In some cases the vowel *-i-* has been generalized to form an interfix between consonant-final first members and consonant-initial second members."

Comment: @TKR which book is that?

Comment: @Tristan Michael Weiss, Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin.

Comment: @JackPliskin I'm sure there are non-SE resources out there on this topic, but it was also covered here. [Here's a good question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/what-cases-were-used-in-compounds) in which TKR provides some nice rules. You can see further discussions [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/forming-a-compound-with-the-second-word-starting-with-a-vowel) and [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16593/what-is-the-best-way-to-invent-compound-words-in-latin).